# Calling an exported function by a string value of the function name

Tags: javascript, reactjs

This is a very simple example of what I am trying to achieve, basically I want to call a function by a string value of it's name, e.g. "hello" should call hello()

I have a helper.js file which contains an exported function e.g.

```
export function hello() {
    console.log('is it me you`re looking for?');
}
```

I am importing this into another js file for usage

```
import {hello} from './helper';
```

I have tried using eval, window and new Function to call my function but no luck

```
//getting console error "hello is not defined"

eval('hello()');  

var fn = window['hello()'];
fn();

var fn = new Function('hello()');
fn();
```

If I wrap the function like so, the eval fires the wrapper.

```
function helloWrapper() {
    hello();
}

eval('helloWrapper()');
```

I just cant seem to fire the exported hello() function directly. I have around 10 functions I'll need to fire so having a wrapper for each seems a bit hacky and wondering if there is a way I can achieve this?

Any help would be greatly appreciated if anyone can point me in the right direction.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Try `eval("hello")()`!

Comment: `eval("hello()")` should work just fine -- but it's not how you should do this. :-)

Comment: (`hello`...`is it me you're looking for`...brilliant)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`eval("hello()")` should work just fine -- but it's not how you should do this. :-)

Instead, build an object containing the functions:

```
import {hello} from './helper'; // In some environments, these need the
import {groot} from './groot';  // .js on the filenames.
// ...

const functions = {hello, groot/*, ... */};
```

and then call them like this:

```
functions[name]();
```

[Live example on plnkr.co](https://plnkr.co/edit/rP5bOARzb8b9ORHn9C1N?p=preview)

Comment: Additionally, though im not sure if this is a better or acceptable method, you could try `if (typeof hello === 'function') { hello(); }

Comment: Perfect! Thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 2):

Generally, referring functions by their names is unsafe in client-side code - or any other that can be minified. The approach explained in the question will work only because `hello` isn't just function name but an import. Due to how ES modules work, import names will be preserved on minification.

In order for a function to be referred by its name, it should be object property. In case of imports there's already such object, it's module export:

```
import * as helper from './helper';

helper['hello']();
```

In case there are multiple modules where functions may originate from, there should be intermediate module that re-exports them.

```
export * from './helper';
export * from './another-helper';
```

All functions from underlying modules will be available as properties when it's imported as `*`:

```
import * as helper from './reexported-helpers';

helper['hello']();
helper['bye']();
```